# Wrap block to use refinement

Tags: ruby, refinements

Given the following refinement:

```
module StringRefinement
  refine String do
    def bar
      length
    end
  end
end
```

I want to implement a module to execute blocks using my refinement:

```
module Demo
  using StringRefinement

  def self.wrap(*args, &block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end
```

And now I should be able to use it like this:

```
Demo.wrap { puts "some text".bar }
```

Which doesn't work :-(

I've been playing with the block binding, yield, context, singleton_class... but I still cannot get this to work.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your `using StringRefinement` statement outside of your module.

Check the following paragraph from the docs:

> You may only activate refinements at top-level, not inside any class, module or method scope.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html#label-Scope

Comment: Thanks! actually I did came up with a similar example and it did fail. However I've just realized it is a Pry bug. I compiled my old test code and just noticed that it was valid from the very beginning... outside Pry

Comment: Note that this is no longer true.  You may now activate refinements inside modules (and therefore inside classes).  You may not do it in method scope.